# How to get print area range?

Tags: vba, excel, pdf, export

I want to create a Save as... button in an UserForm.

When I click it, a dialog appears to save the print area range of activesheet as a *.pdf file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how to export in PDF the print area of the active sheet :

```
Dim Ws As Worksheet
Set Ws = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
ws.Range(ws.PageSetup.PrintArea).ExportAsFixedFormat _
    Type:=xlTypePDF _
    FileName:="sales.pdf" _
    Quality:=xlQualityStandard _
    DisplayFileAfterPublish:=False
```

You just need to change `"sales.pdf"` to fit your purpose! ;)